# NNS: Is there a way to omit certain features in a prediction?

Tags: scikit-learn, knn, amazon-sagemaker

I'd like to train a nearest-neighbor search model with something like the following -

```
        | feature_A | feature_B | feature_C |
---------------------------------------------
point_1 |       0.0 |       5.1 |      94.9 |
point_2 |      80.7 |      35.3 |      64.7 |
```

And so on, with many more features and data points.

We can then pass a point for prediction, such as `[0.3, 5.0, 94.0] -> returns point_1` as is typical in nearest-neighbor search.

What I'd like to do, also, is pass a value for a certain feature or subset of features and return the closest point, ignoring all other features, like so:

`[None, 5.0, None] -> returns point_1`

`[80.0, None, 64.7] -> returns point_2`

The problem is that these nulls can't be passed to the model and they can't really be inferred to be 0.0 as this is not what the prediction is asking for. The feature needs to be omitted entirely from the calculation.

Is there a way to do this natively using Sagemaker/Scikit-learn libraries without having to build multiple models or write a custom implementation of NNS?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way you can use the trained model to predict points with missing values without some kind of imputation like zero, mean, etc. I guess your best bet would be to use something like maximum likelihood imputation which will rightly predict the missing values, which can then be used for clustering.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the problem of doing prediction for data with missingness is hard and not solvable.

To put it in statistical terms: The predicted nearest neighbor for some test point `xₜ` is denoted `ŷ(xₜ)`. Let some of the components of `xₜ` be missing, so we write `xₜ=(zₜ,wₜ)`, where the components `wₜ` is missing. Then, the confidence in that the model predicts `k` can be written like `Pr(ŷ(xₜ)=k)=P(ŷ(zₜ)=k)= ∫I(k=ŷ(zₜ,w))p(w|zₜ)dw`, where `I(t)=1` if `t=true` and `0` otherwise. Finally, you could select the prediction `ỹ(xₜ)` to be the mode of `Pr(ŷ(xₜ)=k)`, i.e. `ỹ(xₜ) = argmax_k Pr(ŷ(xₜ)=k)`.

This is a tough problem, since you need to estimate some conditional densities to compute the integral. You would also need to compute the integral for all possible nearest neighbors.

If you make some restricting assumption, such as Missing Completely At Random, then the problem simplifies, as `p(w|zₜ)=p(w)` from the independence. Your predictions will probably worsen, though. There is no simple way to resolve this problem.

Thus, you need a trade-off between statistical soundness and practical application. This is usually made by some kind of imputation. I think you should have some imputation technique that captures the correlations in the data reasonable well.

I would probably use the [knn-imputer in sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.KNNImputer.html#sklearn.impute.KNNImputer) to impute the missing values, and then just go for nearest-neighbor search on the imputed data.

Comment: Thank you for the very informative answer - unfortunately, as you said, it is not really a solution. Imputation here skews the prediction. Maybe KNN/NNS are not the right fit for this type of problem

Answer (score 0):

SageMaker K- nearest neighbor algorithm does not support passing null for a subset of features.